# In Laravel can I use a path to a public file directly without using asset or url functions?

Tags: laravel

If I have a file `css/style.css` inside the `public` folder. Can I include this file in a `.blade.php` file using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

instead of

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/style.css')}}">
```

Or what's the difference between the two cases?

Comment: yes, you can...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if the style files are placed in the public directory, you can write the path to them without asset helper and everything will work.  However, if the resources you need are outside the public directory, this helper is indispensable.  I think the [file storage documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem) will suit you